# Drasha Le'Chasuna Le'HaRamban

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, internet, ramban

I'm looking for an online copy of "Drasha Le'Chasuna Le'HaRamban".

I seem to have found one at some point in time and printed it out (picture below). (However, I might have gotten it from my friend's Otzar HaChachma.)

[image: Title page of a sefer with the title "Drasha Le'Chasuna Le'HaRamban"]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find the sefer online [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49095&st=&pgnum=319&hilite=), from HebrewBooks.org.